# Deploying Wordpress for clients - what do they have access to?

Tags: wp-admin, user-access, deployment

I've developed websites from scratch up till now and would like to switch to using Wordpress to save time and money.

I've done some theme customization and plugin work so far. I can see that users can update posts and customize themes themselves from `/wp-admin`.

What I'm concerned about it - is that how projects are generally deployed in wordpress? That the client has access to customize pretty much everything themselves? Do they really get to see all this?

[image]

I've generally made custom CMSs for clients based on whatever their website was, but somehow I feel like this is a bit much for clients to have access to? Or is it normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a plugin named [Adminize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/) that will allow you to completely customize what the client can see in the admin.

If you use this plugin you can set yourself up as Admin and then give your client a lesser role, which will allow you to continue to have administrative control over the site.

Answer (score 1):

lets say it depends on you, but we have two different ways for this:

1. end the contract after finishing the website: in this way after finishing the process of developing and designing the website we teach the client what to do with his/her admin panel and give them full access for that!
2. Support Contract after finishing the website: in this way after finishing the website we never let the client have a full access to admin panel! never!